# Postgresql transpose rows to columns

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have this query

```
select * from sales

       shop |    date    |    hour   | row_no | amount
 -----------+------------+-----------+--------+-----------
     shop_1 | 2012-08-14 | 00:08:00  | P01    | 10
     shop_2 | 2012-08-12 | 00:12:00  | O05    | 40
     shop_2 | 2012-08-12 | 00:12:00  | A01    | 20
```

I have 1 millon rows,  I can do this query

```
select shop, SUM(amount) 
from sales 
group by shop

       shop |   amount   |    
 -----------+------------+
     shop_1 |   5666     |  
     shop_2 |   4044     |  
     shop_3     4044     |
```

But I need to spend the days at the columns and I do not know if they could help me do this

```
       shop |    2012-08-1    |    2012-08-2   | 2012-08-3 |
 -----------+------------+-----------+--------+-----------
     shop_1 |      4005       |      5667     |      9987  |     
     shop_2 |      4333      |      4554     |      1234  |     
     shop_3 |      4555       |      6778     |      6677 |
```

Would be group by store in the rows, and group by days in the columns in postgresql

Comment: Search for crosstab

Comment: He heard some crosstab but did anyone know how to use it?

Comment: Cross tab requires you to know the dimensions of the table produced. You won't know that unless you know how many days you've got or want. Do you? Do you want every day represented or just a week, because "every day" requires dynamic sql AND crosstab.

Comment: Also check https://github.com/hnsl/colpivot which can discover the columns

Answer (score 0):

First, you must install `tablefunc` extension. Since version 9.1 you can do it using create extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;

select * from crosstab (  
    select shop, date, SUM(amount) 
    from sales 
    group by shop

    'select date from sales order by 1') 
AS ct(shop: text,  '2012-08-1' text, '2012-08-2' text, '2012-08-3' text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use crosstab to the achieve the desired results, here is a solution:

```
SELECT * FROM CROSSTAB(
  'SELECT shop, date, amount FROM sales ORDER BY 1,2',
  'SELECT DISTINCT date FROM sales ORDER BY 1'
) AS ct(shop text, "2012-08-12" int, "2012-08-14" int);
```

You can also check here: [DbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jQJnKSMr)

Explanation: Crosstab function takes two arguments, a source query and a category query. Source query provides the data to be pivoted and category query provides the column names for pivot table. You can checkout the official documentation here: [tableFunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html).

> crosstab ( source_sql text, category_sql text ) → setof record
> Produces a “pivot table” with the value columns specified by a second query.